# Matlab Database Toolbox - Warning: com.mysql.jdbc.Connection@6e544a45 is not serializable

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc, matlab

I'm connecting to a MySQL database through the Matlab Database Toolbox in order to run the same query over and over again within 2 nested for loops.  After each iteration I get this warning:

```
Warning: com.mathworks.toolbox.database.databaseConnect@26960369 is not serializable 
  In Import_Matrices_DOandT_julaugsept_inflow_nomettsed at 476 
Warning: com.mysql.jdbc.Connection@6e544a45 is not serializable 
  In Import_Matrices_DOandT_julaugsept_inflow_nomettsed at 476 
Warning: com.mathworks.toolbox.database.databaseConnect@26960369 not serializable 
  In Import_Matrices_DOandT_julaugsept_inflow_nomettsed at 476 
Warning: com.mysql.jdbc.Connection@6e544a45 is not serializable 
  In Import_Matrices_DOandT_julaugsept_inflow_nomettsed at 476
```

My code is basically structured like this:

```
%Server
host = 
user = 
password = 
dbName = 

%# JDBC parameters
jdbcString = sprintf('jdbc:mysql://%s/%s', host, dbName);
jdbcDriver = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver';

%# Create the database connection object
conn = database(dbName, user , password, jdbcDriver, jdbcString);
setdbprefs('DataReturnFormat', 'numeric');

%Loop
for SegmentNum=3:41;
    for tl=1:15;
    tic;
    sqlquery=['giant string'];
    results = fetch(conn, sqlquery);
    (some code here that saves the results into a few variables)

    save('inflow.mat');
    end
end

time = toc

close(conn);
clear conn
```

Eventually, after some iterations the code will crash with this error:

```
Error using database/fetch (line 37)
  Query execution was interrupted

Error in Import_Matrices_DOandT_julaugsept_inflow_nomettsed (line
466)
results = fetch(conn, sqlquery);
```

Last night it errored after 25 iterations.  I have about 600 iterations total I need to do, and I don't want to have to keep checking back on it every 25.  I've heard there can be memory issues with database connection objects...is there a way to keep my code running?

Comment: Was there more to that last error statement provided?

Comment: Yes, I didn't remember to save it, but it errored on the fetch() command.

Comment: If you could run it again, and post the entire error, it would help considerably.

Comment: Wow, I had a moment there...I did save the error and it's in the post above...that's the whole thing.  I should get some more sleep!

Answer (score 3):

Let's take this one step at a time.

> Warning: com.mathworks.toolbox.database.databaseConnect@26960369 is not serializable

This comes from this line

```
save('inflow.mat');
```

You are trying to save the database connection. That doesn't work. Try specifying the variables you wish to save only, and it should work better.

There are a couple of tricks to excluding the values, but honestly, I suggest you just find the most important variables you wish to save, and save those. But if you wish, you can piece together a solution from [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/293535).

```
save inflow.mat a b c d e
```

Comment: Makes sense.  I want to save all the variables in the workspace...is there a way to specify savings all variables but not the connection?

Comment: Each iteration adds additional variables, so I can't manually specify which ones I want to save.  I think I can save what I want using '-regexp' since all the variable names begin with the same characters, and that will exclude the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the query in a `try` `catch` block. Whenever you catch an error reset the connection to the database which should free up the object.

```
nQuery = 100;

while(nQuery>0)
   try
      query_the_database();
      nQuery = nQuery - 1;
   catch
      reset_database_connection();
   end
end
```

Comment: I've never used `try catch`, so this may be a silly question, but why do I need the while statement?  Can I not just put the `try catch end` part within my nested for loops?

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate main reason for this is that database connection objects are TCP/IP ports and multiple processes cannot access the same port. That is why database connection object are not serialized. Ports cannot be serialized.

Workaround is to create a connection with in the for loop.